# Create more than one lines break in php

Tags: php, string

I am trying to create more than one line break between 2 strings.

I am repeating (echo '
';) each time i need 1 line break.

Can i write only one statement to add more than one line break?

Comment: If you downvote how about having the courage to put your name to a comment on why?

Comment: i didn't but considering the quality of the question, i'm not surprised.

Answer (score 1):

use `str_repeat` for repeating text.

E.g. `echo str_repeat("<br>", 10); will add 10 line breaks`

Comment: it works fine with me. Thank you Raidenace

Answer (score 0):

What about just using control chars to get what you want eg, although with html output you may need to use 
 tags instead

```
echo("foo\n\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the new line character (`\n`):

```
echo "line 1\nline2\n";
```

Returns:

```
line1
line2
```

Comment: str_repeat works fine with me, but \n does not work at all even if i need only one line break, I know it should work, but it's not!

Comment: a line break for what? in html you need <br> or <p></p> or css for a regular text file \n is fine, you did not specify in your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
 echo "string </br></br> string";
```

Comment: this will give me only 1 line break, i said i want more than one line break!